# Can't open userform2 while userform1 code is running

Tags: vba, runtime-error, userform

I'm trying to add some stuff to my existing code to further automate things. 
I have a userform1 with some code. If a certain event while running the code happens I need to open a new userform2 where the user has to use some checkboxes to alter some values on the sheet used by userform1. after the user is done I want them to close userform2 and the code to continue running(userform1 paused/hidden?).
But I can't get userform2 to open. It shows runtime error 13 with highlighting

```
    userform2.show
```

I've already tried putting both userforms as modeless.
I've tried

```
me.hide
```

before opening userform2.

Is there a way to open userform2 and continue the code after closing it or do I need to find another way?

Code to summon userform1:

```
Button on Excel Sheet_click()
with combobox1
.additem XX
.
.
end with

with combobox2
.additem XX
.
.
end with

with combobox2
.additem XX
.
.
end with

userform1.show
end sub
```

code to summon userform2 (or not) in part:

```
if sheet1.range("a1") = 1 then
 do this
elseif sheet1.range("a1") > 1 then
userform1.hide
userform2.show  'highlighted when runtime error 13 pops up
end if
```

Initialize event of userform2:

```
Private Sub UserForm2_Initialize()
Dim DBB As Worksheet
Set DBB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("BB")
With userform2
    .labelfield1.Caption = DBB.Range("D5")
    .
    .

    .labelfield2.Caption = DBB.Range("D5") - DBB.Range("D10")
    .
    .

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please add both the code how you load/show `userform1` and the code before and after `userform2.show` to your question?

Comment: @Hel O'Ween done.

Comment: And you get a [run time error 13](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-type-mismatch/) at the line `userform2.show`? What is in the initialize event of Userform2?

Comment: In order to stop at the error in userform2 change your settings to _Break in class module_, look [here](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-tips-for-handling-errors-in-vba/)

Comment: @Storax: Gotcha! The error was in the labelfield2.caption line since only part of them were filled! I probably need to build some code to check for filled cells on the sheet and hiding empty labelingfields. 
Thanks!